# How can dictionaries be tyrants?

Tags: dictionaries, catch-phrases

Sometimes you might hear the phrase, *tyranny of the dictionary* Is there a way to express succinctly just what that means?

Comment: I think this question would be improved if, instead of using the vague "sometimes you might hear the phrase," you instead shared where you've heard or read this. Expounding a little bit more on why you're confused would help, too.

Comment: Although more broad than your phrase, there is [prescriptivism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) ("Normative practices may prescribe on such aspects of language use as spelling").

Comment: I concur with J.R.  Without some context we're only guessing what it *might* mean. I can think of two almost opposite senses in which I might use it.

Comment: How much more succinct than "tyranny of the dictionary" do you need to be?

Comment: Guys, was this closed because the image of a dictionary-wielding mob was just too close to home?

Comment: 2all: Tyranny of the dictionary is commonly used by professors...especially in the letter arts. It is advanced as a reason many if most are impeded from literary mastery. Reading comprehension seem to be a lost concept in the interconnected universe. The question did not say or imply I don't know the meaning--or have no expertise; I only asked for a few suggestions for succintly explaining. I realize that it is an academic even erudite concept, and not broadly known to...who are taught to lean heavily on dictionary. I am confident there are those able to repond, those who cant will ignore.

Comment: @lex I’ve never heard a professor use it.

Comment: Thank Zairja for the prescriptivism info. Yes, it does shoot wide of the mark but a bull's eye is not so meaningful without a wider, "target" around itself. In that regard, some aspects of dictionary usage as a form of "pedantically prescribed" usage, can also readily be seen as antithetical to the notion of dictionary tyranny avoidance--which is why I will peruse again for some reference to the latter (TotD) in article you provided.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries have both [descriptive and prescriptive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary#Prescriptive_vs._descriptive), and depending on the philosophy of the editors, different dictionaries may tend to promote one or the other.  Most dictionaries today aim to be descriptive, but by their very existence cannot help but be prescriptive as well.

The **descriptive** function of a dictionary is to describe the language as it exists:  what language users say or write, and what those language users mean when they say/write it.

The **prescriptive** function of a dictionary is norm-setting: once the words of a language are described in the dictionary, it starts to become the standard, possibly stifling innovations in the way words are used.  So for example, parents tell their children to go look a word up in the dictionary rather than just telling the child the meaning of the word as the parent understands it.  People playing scrabble look up strings of letters in the dictionary to see if they are, in fact, considered words.  Writers consult the dictionary to see if, according to the dictionary, they can use a word in a particular way.

So "tyranny of the dictionary" is used as a cute way to describe the prescriptive function of a dictionary, usually by someone who has been caught using a word in a nonstandard (or "wrong" depending on the situation and how you look at it) way.

It is also a play on words with "[tyranny of the majority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyranny_of_the_majority)" which is widely used, and has been widely used for a long time in discussions of democracy.  So that definitely gives it a boost in usage.

Comment: I can appreciate that. And I time tested it and it does have virtue of brevity. With some modification it could work nicely.

Comment: Umm ... you might want to modify that first sentence. You can't trust that number that Google puts up at the top. Google offers in fact only 21 hits, of which two are this post and another by the same OP.

Comment: Good point.  Very deceptive of Google.  Deleted that sentence. (Which, for the record, reported Google saying there were 800k hits for the phrase "tyranny of the dictionary".  Which it did and does say, but incorrectly as there were really only three pages of results).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard this phrase, but I think I get what it means. A [tyrant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tyrant?s=t) is a "ruler who uses power oppressively or unjustly."

When you rely on dictionary definitions exclusively, you leave no room for informal, colloquial and regional uses which may not appear in a dictionary. Language moves and changes faster and more subtly than any dictionary can keep up with. Just because something isn't in the dictionary doesn't mean that its use is somehow "incorrect." Have a look at Zairja's link to prescriptivism in the comments.

However, a dictionary can be a useful tool. I use my various dictionaries every day. I even used one in this answer!

Comment: I would add--and this goes a way towards explaining the tyranny aspect--that, unless used judiciously, it comes to suppress literary license; and, accordingly, the (growth in) capacity for critical thinking and dialog...and creativity (in that dictionary addicts) stand to have impeded any bent of mind to try new ways of expressing themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary isn't the actual tyrant; the consensus-driven herd behaviour which forms around the dictionary is the source of the oppression.  Picture a dictionary-wielding mob pelting dissenters with hard-bound copies of the OED and you're there.

Comment: ...indeed, and mightily so